# Getting TypeError "getStaticPaths is not a function" when using framer-motion in Next.js

Tags: next.js, framer-motion

I'm having an issue with framer-motion. I'm trying to play around with it but I'm met with this error:

```
Error [TypeError]: getStaticPaths is not a function
    at buildStaticPaths (/Users/x/coding/projects/personal/website/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:699:39)
    at Object.loadStaticPaths (/Users/x/coding/projects/personal/website/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/static-paths-worker.js:103:46)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  digest: undefined
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```js
import { gif } from "@/public/assets";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
  <div className="w-full shadow-navbarShadow h-20 lg:h-[12vh] sticky top-0 z-50 bg-bodyBgColor px-4">
    <div className="max-w-container h-full mx-auto py-1 font-bodyFont flex items-center justify-between">
      <motion.div initial={{opacity: 0}} animate={{opacity: 1}} transition={{duration: 0.5}}>
        <Image className="w-40" src={gif} alt="logo" />
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}

export default Nav;
```

I've installed the latest version of framer-motion (10.12.20) and also downgraded to 7.3.2 but to no avail.

Any help with this issue is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is your nextjs version?

Comment: @KannuMandora Hi! My Next.js version is 13.4.9.

Comment: Next js 13 if you use app directory than getStaticProps is not work

Comment: @KannuMandora I see, thanks for the info. I will downgrade to an older version and see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next js 13 if you use app directory than getStaticProps is not work because you can use `cache` method and pass `force-cache | no-store` parameters in fetch API so your page act like static pages

Comment: Oh okay. Appreciate the help! Very new to Next.js. If you were to solve this issue, how would you approach it?

Comment: Thank you! Downgraded to version 12 and it worked.

Comment: I just read the documentation and create project on Next.Js & you can connect me with on social media. https://mandorakannu.tech/

Comment: @MiniDracaena . Thanks. I downgraded my Next.js from 13.4.10 to 13.2.4 and it worked for me. 